# Iterating over a Pandas Dataframe column and adding its elements to a Python Collections Counter object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, python-collections

I have a pandas dataframe of N columns of integer object values. The values in the columns are associated with outcome of a particular random experiment. For example, if I were to call df.head():

```
    0   1   2  3
0  13   4   0  5
1   8   2  16  6
2   6  20  14  0
3  17   4   8  4
4  17   2  12  0
```

What I am interesting in doing is identifying the number of times each of unique values occur for a particular column. Concerning ourselves with column 0 only, I may wish to know of the number of times I have observe the value '17' this experiment, and in our box above we can see this occurred twice over the first 5 entries in column 0.

**What would be the optimal method of doing this, via Pandas itself or otherwise?**

The first approach I considered was to collapse that column down into a Dictionary where the Key is the observed data value, and the Dictionary Value being associated with the count of that Particular Key. I used the Counter datastructure from Python Collections.

```
# converting the Dataset into a Pandas Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("newdataset.txt",
                 header=None,
                 #skiprows=0,
                 delim_whitespace=True)

print(df.head())

user0Counter = Counter()

for dataEntry in df[0]:
    user0Counter.update(dataEntry)
```

This leads to a type error.

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d2a83c38d0d0> in <module>
----> 1 import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''~/dir/foo/bar.py''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();exec(compile(__code, '''~/dir/foo/bar.py''', 'exec'));

~/dir/foo/bar.py in <module>
     28 
     29 for dataEntry in df[0]:
---> 30     user0Counter.update(dataEntry)
     31 
     32 print(len(user0Counter))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py in update(*args, **kwds)
    651                     super(Counter, self).update(iterable) # fast path when counter is empty
    652             else:
--> 653                 _count_elements(self, iterable)
    654         if kwds:
    655             self.update(kwds)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If I replace the user0Counter.update() method with a print(dataEntry) block, there is no issue iterating over df[0].

```
    0   1   2  3
0  13   4   0  5
1   8   2  16  6
2   6  20  14  0
3  17   4   8  4
4  17   2  12  0
13
8
6
17
17
1
1
4
6
19
3
11
3
4
12
7
1
9
4
2
1
2
5
1
2
13
```

And so forth.

Comment: are you looking for `df[0].value_counts()`? it gives a pd.Series with the number of occurrence of each element in the column 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` directly.

```
import pandas as pd

df['col_frequency'] = df.groupby(['col_to_count'])['col_to_count'].count()
```